# WMS projection doesn't match basemap

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have a flex viewer 3.0 map in wgs 84 (4326) (ESRI basemap) with a wms which is 4326 as well. for some reason the wms doesn't overlay correctly. it is way off. appears on the maps but it is flattened quite a bit.

Comment: Are you able to view the wms layer in another tool to verify it displays as you expect it to and is set up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I would try again with Spherical Mercator, I haven't used the ESRI base maps but in web mapping EPSG 3785 is the de-facto standard and likely the source of the problem.

Comment: Careful with the EPSG code, there is already *far* too much confusion on the web around this. You mean 3857